# HMVC ISSUE. Cant load controllers or models

Tags: angularjs, html, codeigniter, hmvc

excuse me for my bad english.

i'm working on a web app using angular js and codeigniter, using third party libraries as HMVC (github) and Ui router for angularjs. i've installed HMVC libraries as shown on multiple youtube tutos in my main project but i can't manage to make them work.

the problem is i can not load controllers or models inside modules folder or subfolders. at the begining i thought it was due to some of the routes i got on my project so i've decided to try HMVC on a completely new installation.  Found this tutorial, followed it >> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDqwXpEQ8Pc << the same result neither models or controlls are loaded.

i've tried

```
< $config['modules_locations'] = array(
APPPATH.'modules/' => '../modules/', );
```

changing routes and Modules folder to web root changing 'modules_location'. anything seem to work

i'm extending controller classes as MX_Controller -> some other stackoverflow solutions i found about this its for not extending correctly.

I'm only able to call Controllers On >application>controllers on codeigniter default folders. But i can not load models inside >Application>models. shows error as follows: "Unable to locate the model you have specified: xxModel"

can't load controllers inside >application>modules>xx>Controllers>xxController.

my .Htaccess file this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

#Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
#such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
#request to index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#This last condition enables access to the images and css folders, and the robots.txt file
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|public|images|robots\.txt|css)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

and my folders look like this:

- root
- - system
- - application
- - - Controllers -> (only load default controller in here)
- - - Models -> (not found models loaded from above controllers)
- - - modules --> (not load controllers from here)
- - **modules**  --> (should be here)
- - - module
- - - - Controllers.
- - Html   -> (views folder, can load views from controllers in            Application>controllers).

Help please!. thanks. let me know to post some more info if necessary.

Comment: Which version of CI are you using? Why do you have two modules folders as you only need to have /application/modules?

Comment: Modules location mustn't be in publicly available location.

Comment: i'm using ci3 i dont have 2 modules folder. i have one inside application folder. but does not work at all. the folder (bold) is where i want to save the modules folder, and my app should be able to look for my models and controllers from there. i read somewhere that putting modules folder outside application folder its a good practice. thanks for your answer.